# Selenium IWebDriver - problems with foreach in C# code

Tags: c#, wordpress, selenium

I'm creating a Selenium framework based on a tutorial on Pluralsight (where I'm not a paying member any longer, and hence have no way to get support), but I think I've run into a problem where the tutorial code worked on an earlier version of Selenium, but not the current one.

```
public class FFDriver {
    public static IWebDriver Instance { get; set; }

    public static void Initialize () {
            Instance = new FirefoxDriver();
            Instance.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
    }

    public static void Wait(TimeSpan timeSpan) {
            Thread.Sleep((int)(timeSpan.TotalSeconds * 1000));
    }

    public static void Close () {
            Instance.Close();
    }
}
```

This is the driver Object I'm using for opening Firefox, navigating etc. Other classes use this.

The code below (from another class using the FFDriver class) fails:

```
public static void TrashPost (string title) {
var rows = FFDriver.Instance.FindElement(By.TagName("tr"));

foreach (var row in rows) {
    ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> links = null;
    links = row.FindElements(By.LinkText(title));

    if (links.Count > 0) {
        Actions action = new Actions(FFDriver.Instance);
            action.MoveToElement(links[0]);
        action.Perform();
            row.FindElement(By.ClassName("submitdelete")).Click();
            return;
    }
}
```

The code reads the rows of the posts on a Wordpress site and deletes the post with a given title, using the Action class in Selelinum to hover over the post and click the Trash link.

It fails with this error:

```
Error 1 foreach statement cannot operate on variables 
oftype 'OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement' because 
'OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement' does not contain a public definition 
for 'GetEnumerator' ...
```

Apparently, it has worked before on the version of Selenium used by the tutorial I'm taking it from. It's a video turorial, and I'm actually watching him type in the code without any errors or warnings from VS.

I'm not very good With C# yet - still Learning the basics - so I'm really not sure how to attack this problem. There might be other ways to solve this, of course, and I'll take any suggestions anyone might have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FindElement()` only returns one element.

You need to use `FindElements()` *(plural)*  to loop through them.

```
var rows = FFDriver.Instance.FindElements(By.TagName("tr"));
```

Comment: Oh my. A typo. That's embarrassing. Thanks for spotting it, though :-)